# Quick inverse trigonometric integration question.

Tags: calculus, integration

I am a little confused here, how does removing $1/2$ from the function to the outside of the integral get rid of the $t$ in the numerator in this problem?

$$\eqalign{
\int\dfrac t{t^4+25}dt & = \dfrac12\int\dfrac{1}{(t^2)^2+5^2}(2)\,dt \\
&= \dfrac1{10}\arctan\left(\dfrac{t^2}5\right)+C
}$$

Comment: It doesn't. The second expression should have a $(2t)\;dt$ not $(2)\;dt$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute $u=t^2$, so that $du = 2t \,dt$.  In yours, the $t$ is missing, should be $(2t)$.

Comment: This is from my textbook. The textbook is wrong?

Comment: If it has $(2)$ and not $(2t)$, then yes, it is wrong.  Most textbooks nowadays have a web site of errata.  Why not see if this is listed?

Answer (score 1):

You do it like this:
 $$\int \frac{t}{t^4+25} dt$$
For the integrand $\frac{t}{t^4+25}$, substitute $u = t^2$ and  $du = 2 t dt$:
 $$= \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{u^2+25} du$$
The integral of $\frac{1}{u^2+25}$ is $\frac{1}{5} \operatorname{arctan}(\frac{u}{5})$:
 $$= \frac{1}{10} \operatorname{arctan}(\frac{u}{5})+C$$
Substitute back for $u = t^2$:
 $$= \frac{1}{10} \operatorname{arctan}(\frac{t^2}{5})+C$$

Comment: The answer above is from the text book is their process incorrect?

Comment: There's obviously a typo in the text  book. See wckronholm's comment

Comment: @Matt: The answer you quoted seems to agree with this one. Presumably the missing $t$ in the solution that you quote is a typo.